# Execute Imediate com quebra de linhas ficando Inválido Package

Tags: oracle, pl-sql, oracle10g, oracle11c

estou criando uma package dinamicamente ou seja:

```
DECLARE
  vpackageletras VARCHAR2(2000);
  vvalorpossuia  VARCHAR2(10);
  vvalorpossuib  VARCHAR2(10);

BEGIN

  IF letras.possuia THEN
    vvalorpossuia := 'TRUE';
  ELSE
    vvalorpossuia := 'FALSE';
  END IF;
  IF letras.possuib THEN
    vvalorpossuib := 'TRUE';
  ELSE
    vvalorpossuib := 'FALSE';
  END IF;

  vpackageletras := 'CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE letras AS' || CHR(13) ||
                    '  possuiA    CONSTANT BOOLEAN NOT NULL := ' || vvalorpossuia || ';' || CHR(13) ||
                    '  possuiB    CONSTANT BOOLEAN NOT NULL := ' || vvalorpossuia || ';' || CHR(13) || 
                    'END letras;';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vpackageletras;
END;
```

Isso se caso eu queira adicionar uma nova CONSTANT eu so adiciono em baixo, por exemplo, o possuiC, e garanto que não vou perder os dados que ja existe na PACKAGE.

Entretanto quando executo esse script a package letras esta ficando inválida, e ao editar via PLSQL e executar fica válida.

Comment: Desculpe, mas constante é constante , número pi , número e etc   para variáveis use variáveis, para persistir valores em SGBD use tabelas, não vejo razão para se alterar objetos dinamicamente. Mas talvez eu não tenha entendido seu problema.

Comment: Você esta certo, mas essa rotina já existe no sistema onde desenvolvo, e como a mesma esta em mais de 300 cliente e em cada cliente diferente, quero que seja possível adicionar uma nova constante sem perder os valores da atual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estava pensando que o problema estava na quebra de linhas,
então busquei alternativas para isso, ao invés de utilizar o CHR(13) utilizei o CHR(10)

```
Chr(13) = Avanço de linha = Line Feed
Chr(10) = Retorno de Carro = Carriage Return
```

dessa forma a Package não fica mais Inválida.

Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Não precisa colocar um "resolvido" nas perguntas. Quando você assinala uma resposta como válida, subentende-se que o problema foi resolvido. :)

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti Sabe me informar por que alguns posts colocam [Resolvido] ? (obrigado pela dica)

Comment: Porque as outras pessoas não sabiam disso. :) Acho que é meio que um hábito herdado dos fóruns de discussão.

Comment: Verdade, lembro que em foruns era assim mesmo. Obrigado @RodrigoRigotti